# php.ini file is edited but still changes are not reflecting

Tags: php-fpm, php.ini

I used phpinfo() in the code and it shows that the Loaded Configuration File is /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini, I edited the upload_max_filesize to 500M and restarted the fpm service using, sudo systemctl restart php7.4-fpm but still the changes have not taken place.

Comment: Most likely, there is a pool for your site.
Check in `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/`

Comment: I don't know what is pool, how to check for it and solve the issue please?

Comment: Hi @Sting Please list all runing services with php in their name. You may need something like `sudo systemctl reload php7.4-fpm.service`

Comment: @Sting Did you check in the catalogue I mentioned?

Comment: @gildux - the original post already explains that it has been done.

Comment: Yes @Orphans the original post said it restarted fpm service. As it's about FPM, i'm warning to be sure to restart the good pool service too, like you warned to be sure to edit the right configuration. I've accrossed the case many times, when one think dealing with the right service but they are sibiling dansing.

Comment: OP explicitly mentioned that they did "sudo systemctl restartphp7.4-fpm", you basically said that they should run the same command again.

Comment: @Orphans, what to check for exactly?, I have a www.conf file in this path /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/. Should I edit it or something?